# asp.net: determine "height" of html without client-side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

Using vb.net in a webapplication, .net 2.0

I have users enter multiple text bits that my app then merges into a complex table. That table is then being sent via email to multiple users. I need to know the height of the resulting table. Testing multiple versions, I can pick the shortest, most compact one, with the least amount of empty space.

Thanks to Andrew for steering me away to run browser windows on the server in order to have JS return the table height to me. I've found the solution for my problem: create an image from my html and measure the height of that.

Using the - for my purposes - free library from http://www.websitesscreenshot.com/ I've created this function: feed html, get height of well-rendered html:

`Function getTableHeight(ByVal html As String) As Integer
    Dim _WebsitesScreenshot As New WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot()
    Dim _Result As WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result
    With _WebsitesScreenshot
      _Result = .CaptureHTML(html) 
      If _Result = WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result.Captured Then
        Return .GetImage.Height
      ElseIf _Result = WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result.Failed Then
        Response.Write("Failed")
        Return 0
      ElseIf _Result = WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result.Timeout Then
        Response.Write("Timeout")
        Return 0
      End If
    End With
    _WebsitesScreenshot.Dispose()
  End Function`

Comment: Thanks to Andrew for steering me away to run browser windows on server. I've found the solution for my problem: create an image from my html and measure the height of that.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a browser process on the server (and communicating back and forth with your server process) would be a very strange way of doing this. Easiest way would be to write some heuristics on the server to detect the optimum layout based on which data fields have been filled in, how much data in each field, how many rows etc.

Otherwise if you are getting the user to decide, can't you just hide the options that are really tall? You could use a client-side templating language to construct the tables based on the data if you aren't already, and as you say just detect the heights.

If you want to go down the server road you could use node.js and something like https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom I guess - easier than trying to deal with another browser process, but still overkill I would say.